# UL-certified WiFi Wall Switch

Tags: smart-home, networking, wifi, ac-power

I'm looking for a UL-certified WiFi wall switch for programming network effects in Python.

- UL-certified
- Wall-mounted
- Mains-powered
- 2+ physical switches
- Python-programmable.

I want to program some stateful network effects using either [`lifxlan`](https://github.com/mclarkk/lifxlan) or [`Photons`](https://github.com/delfick/photons). Ideally these modules would run directly on the switch but at a bare minimum I need the switch to emit network notifications (such as `switch ID.123 off`) that can in turn be processed by an intermediate server.

This is going to replace a one-way switch in a relatively new US home. There are a many wires in the switch box with 4 different colors of wires. I haven't figured out if any is a neutral. The devices on the circuit are all smart so the switch need not interrupt the power flow - the circuit may be continuously on.

Comment: I still need a wall-mounted, mains-powered device to provide WiFi switching using physical toggles/buttons.

Comment: @jsotola do you have a reference for "shopping questions are off-topic"?  According to [this long-standing meta post](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/176/49) purchace recommendations are fine so long as there is sufficient detail on what the OP is looking for.